# How can I assign an object from Firebase RTDB to a Map<String, String>?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have a food ordering app and want to map the certain varieties a meal can have to radio buttons.

An example of my menu items in my database:

```
menuItem
        J1
           -description:"Tasty milk shake!"
           -img:"assets/images/milkshake.JPG"
           -itemName:"Milk Shake"
           -price:20
           -varieties
                    -var1:"Chocolate"
                    -var2:"Vanilla"
                    -var3:"Strawberry"

menuItem
        J2
           -description:"Best chicken in the country"
           -img:"assets/images/chicken.JPG"
           -itemName:"Full Chicken"
           -price:55
           -varieties
                    -var1:"lemon & Herb"
                    -var2:"medium"
                    -var3:"Peri-Peri"
                    -car4:"Super Hot"
                    -var5:"Preezy"
```

I am able to fetch and display all the other data but I am struggling with the varieties. If someone clicks on a milkshake/chicken they need to see the right options.

I am successfully getting variety options using but not setting them to anything:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _activateListeners();
  }

  void _activateListeners() {
    final itemID = widget.id;
    _varietyStream = _dbRef.child('menuItem/$itemID/varieties').onValue.listen((event) {
      final data = event.snapshot.value;
      setState(() {
        //Map data to somehting here
      });
    });
  }
```

The output of `_activateListeners()` is the following:

```
{var3: Strawberry, var2: Vanilla, var1: Chocolate}
```

I have had no success turning this data into a list that can be used in a `ListView`

I have tried to cast this object to a `Map` and `List`

What can I do?

Comment: Since you have a list of varieties, I expect you'll some sort of `ListView` for it on the `varieties` snapshot. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html

Comment: ListView would be the right way to go , thank you. How would I actually make the list that needs to be displayed, though. With what I am returning it puts all varieties into one place on the list (i.e. [{var1: x, Var2:y}] instead of [x, y]. How do I decode my results? normally you have a  model but I cannot have a set model with a set number of variables for varieties to decode from.

Comment: It looks like the value of your `varieties` property should be a `Map<String,String>`, so if you cast it to that, you can loop over its values like this https://coflutter.com/dart-how-to-get-keys-and-values-from-map/

Comment: It says an object cannot be assigned to `Map<String, String>`. If I convert the object to String and try json.decode` it also does not work because my data is not in proper json format. So if I was getting an object: `{var3: Strawberry, var2: Vanilla, var1: Chocolate}` from the database how do I map this to get each individual flavour as part of a list?

Comment: That error message has come up many times already, so I recommend searching for it. If you can't get it to work after that, edit your question to [show the **minimal** code that allows any of us to reproduce where you are stuck now](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as we've gone quite a long way from your original post by now as far as I can tell.

Comment: I have edited my original post. If I was able to return a JSON format object from the database would this simplify my issue?

Comment: Sure, but it moves us back to my first comment: you'll need to [use a `ListView` to handle the items in that map.](https://www.google.com/search?q=flutter+use+a+%60ListView%60+to+handle+the+items+in+that+map).

Answer (score 0):

I changed my data so that I would get a JSON format object `{"var4": "Preezy", "var2": "Medium", "var3": "Peri-Peri", "var1": "Lemon & Herb"}`

I then used the following method to add my varieties to a list (`[Preezy, Medium, Peri-Peri, Lemon & Herb]`):

```
  void _activateListeners() {
    final itemID = widget.id;
    _varietyStream =
        _dbRef.child('menuItem/$itemID/varieties').onValue.listen((event) {
      var data = event.snapshot.value.toString();
      var decoded = json.decode(data);
      Map<String, dynamic> map = decoded;
      map.entries.map((e) => varietyList.add(e.value)).toList();
    });
  }
```

Using ListView I displayed my list in the form of radio buttons (Which are not functional yet):

```
                    ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: varietyList.length,
                        itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                          return GFRadioListTile(
                            titleText: varietyList[index],
                            size: 25,
                            activeBorderColor: Colors.black,
                            focusColor: Colors.black,
                            type: GFRadioType.basic,
                            value: 0,
                            groupValue: 1,
                            onChanged: (value) {},
                            inactiveIcon: null,
                          );
                        })),
```